# Upper bound on probability of binomial exceeding expectation

Tags: probability, machine-learning

For iid $X_i$ taking values in $\{0, 1\}$ with parameter $E[X_i]$ show that when $nE[X_i] > 1$:
$$P\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n X_i > E[X_i]\right) \leq1/4$$

This inequality is from the proof of Lemma 4.1 in Vapnik's Statistical Learning Theory.

My first thought is to bound this with a normal approximation, but I need this for all n such that $nE[X_i] > 1$. Also, of course Markov's inequality is no help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your probability is $P(n^{-1/2} \sum_1^n (X_i - E[X_i])>0)$. By the CLT, this converges to 1/2 as $n\to\infty$, where your condition $n E[X_i]>1$ is satisfied for $n$ large enough.

So I doubt that the claimed inequality is true.

Comment: I'm quite confident this is a typo in Vapnik's book. The next claim in the lemma uses the opposite statement to what I have above (he applies a lower bound rather than an upper bound). Thanks for your help!